# Bash grep complicated search

Tags: bash, grep

How can I write a searching command **using grep** that will look for a line with a strict requirements. For example it should start with a name, which consist only letters and "-", then follows an ":", then a year or "xxxx", then again an ":", and then a line of letters, digits and "-" of some length. Or may be there is a link where I can read this... I'm trying to find some solution in the Internet for a long time, but can't...

Comment: Can you please share a sample input and a sample output?

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is to pass the grep command a **regular expression** that describes your pattern of interest, on the basis of which grep will match only valid lines.

Taking into account your indications, the following regular expression could do the job:

```
^([A-z]|-)+:([0-9]|xxxx)+:([A-z]|[0-9]|-)+$
```

The expression begins and ends with the `^` and `$` anchors, that indicate the beginning and the end of a line. Then, you basically have three token blocks, separated by `:`, the first matching letters and dashes, the second years or `xxxx`, and the third letters, digits and dashes. `+` is a quantifier, indicating that the preceding token can appear one or more times.

You can use it with grep like so:

```
grep -P "^([A-z]|-)+:([0-9]|xxxx)+:([A-z]|[0-9]|-)+$"
```

The -P option is to indicate to interpret it as a Perl regex and correctly handle hyphens matching.

Comment: I guess I had to write the whole expression, because it is still not working... Lines I work with look like this one:      
@Article{Courtois:1971:readers,      So I need to filter the wrong written ones (right is as I wrote before), so I try to do it this way:      
grep --color -E -n '^@' literatur.bib | grep -E -P -v '([A-z]|-)+:([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|xxxx):([A-z][0-9]|-)+'         
What is wrong?

Comment: In the second grep you should add the begin and end line anchors (^ and $). Then, add "@Article{" as the first token of the expression if it appears in every line.